# Disable Dropdown inside Grid View

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, dropdownlistfor

I am trying to disable couple of drop downs while a checkbox is unselected. I have the drop down populating at the moment, but now I need to enable/disable it accordingly.

**CheckBox**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HPV">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="HpvCheck" runat="server" value="feedback"/>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

**Drop Down List**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HPV Criteria">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList   DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="aqdcode" ID="ddlHPvViolation"  runat="server" DataSource="<%# HpvViolation() %>"/>
      </asp:DropDownList>
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

**THE GRID**

```
protected void gvViolationsCited_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        //GridViewFunctions.FindCellByDataField(e.Row, "LOVRID").Visible = false;
        TableCell idCell = GridViewFunctions.FindCellByDataField(e.Row, "ID");
        idCell.Visible = false;

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            ImageButton lb = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("lbShowModalDialog");
            long id = long.Parse(idCell.Text);
```

**DDL Populate**

```
public IList<LookupItem> HpvViolation()
{
    return LookupDataLoaderService.Instance.LoadLookupData(LookupTables.HPV_VIOLATION_CODE);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using jQuery**

Since the ID of the controls inside a GridView are modified in the HTML output, it is easier to work with the class attribute (especially with jQuery selectors). You can set the `CssClass` property of the input elements:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HPV">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox CssClass="hpvCheck" ID="HpvCheck" runat="server" ... />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HPV Criteria">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList CssClass="hpvViolation" ID="ddlHPvViolation" runat="server" Enabled="false" ... />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And use these class names in the event handler of the CheckBoxes:

```
$('.hpvCheck').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.hpvViolation')[0].disabled = !$(this).find('input')[0].checked;
});
```

In this jQuery function call, the CheckBoxes are found with their `hpvCheck` class name. In the event handler for the `change` event:

1. The parent table row of the CheckBox is found
2. The DropDownList in the table row is found with its `hpvViolation` class name
3. The HTML input element of the ASP.NET CheckBox control is found
4. The `disabled` property of the DropDownList is set according to the `checked` property of the CheckBox

**Using pure Javascript**

If jQuery is not avaible, the same can be done with pure Javascript.

The handler of the `onclick`event of the CheckBox must be set:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HPV">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="HpvCheck" runat="server" onclick="processHpvCheck(this);"  ... />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HPV Criteria">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList CssClass="hpvViolation" ID="ddlHPvViolation" runat="server" Enabled="false" ... />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and defined as follows in Javascript code:

```
function processHpvCheck(chk) {
    // Find the table row that contains the CheckBox
    var container = chk;
    while (container.tagName != 'TR') {
        container = container.parentNode;
    }
    // Find the DropDownList
    var ddl = container.getElementsByClassName('hpvViolation')[0];
    // Enable/disable the DropDownList according to the CheckBox state
    ddl.disabled = !chk.checked;
}
```

Comment: So I tried to implement as you stated above, but the JQuery function does not fire for some reason. Still no luck with this.

Comment: I am tempted to say: this is impossible (since I tested it). You can check the HTML source, in the browser, to see if the class names are really applied to the elements. And just to be sure: the jQuery code must be at the bottom of the page. And jQuery must be available in your page.

Comment: Yes I left it at the bottom of the page. I've tried couple of things and still not able to solve this.

Comment: Is Javascript enabled in your browser?

Comment: Yes, its a current running application and also runs only in IE, so debugging isn't the easiest.

Comment: You can try the code given in this page: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-check-if-jquery-library-is-loaded/.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var txtFacilityID, txtEnfCaseID, facilityID, enfCaseID, txtFacilityDistrictCode, facilityDistrictCode, ddlHPVViolation;

        function pageLoad(sender, args)

Comment: currently its doing that in the page.

Comment: Copy/paste the code given in the link above (comment made 2 minutes ago) and see what you get.

Comment: 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Comment: Seems like the JQuery function is not working properly.

Comment: Yep. jQuery is probably not included in your page. You can Google to see how to include it.

Comment: Included it in the page, JQuery message loads in the page, but still breaking in the code.

Comment: Could I write something like this in the HTML page?

Comment: function ValidateHpvViolation(source, args) {
            if (chkEpaHpv.checked == true) {
                if (ddlHPVViolation.selectedIndex == 0) {
                    args.IsValid = false;

Comment: Since jQuery is not available in your page, I added a "pure Javascript" method to my answer.

Comment: Implemented that in my script and it doesn't do anything. I am running clueless here.

Comment: All that was tested. Please show in your question the full markup of the GridView and the Javascript block.

Comment: Okay here is an update, I missed the "onclick" from your html. Now I click on the checkbox it disables the drop down for a second but it enables by itself.

Comment: AutoPostBack="False". I changed this from True to False. Now if I click on the checkbox its disabled. I need it to be other way around.

Comment: One last thing, don't kill me. How can I initially disable the popup. BTW you've been amazing bro. Thanks so much

Comment: sorry disable the drop down.

Comment: You're welcome! I updated the markup in my answer to show the `Enabled="false"` attribute that will disable the DropDownList initially. I think we finally got it. :-)

Comment: You deserve a medal! May I ask another question? The SelectChanged property to save my dropdown answer. Do I need to do something special for that?

Comment: That is not a small question. It deserves a new post, I think (after a search on StackOverflow or with Google, to see if the procedure is already explained somewhere).

Comment: No problem. Thank you once again. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript Use Following Logic

```
$("#checkbox1").change(function () {

  if (document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked == true) {

     document.getElementById("DropDown1").disabled = true;
  }
  else {

     document.getElementById("DropDown1").disabled = false;
  }

});
```

Comment: I have tried different JavaScript functions but the html does not seem to read it. I will try this.

Comment: I tried your logic, but my javascript is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void grdTaskDataCat1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
         ddlTaskStatus.DataTextField = obj_ds.Tables[0].Columns["STATUS_DESC"].ToString();
                  ddlTaskStatus.DataValueField = obj_ds.Tables[0].Columns["ID"].ToString();
                  ddlTaskStatus.DataSource = obj_ds.Tables[0];
                  ddlTaskStatus.DataBind();
                  ddlTaskStatus.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
      }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Siddharam, welcome to [so]. I suggest you to improve your answer by providing an explanation of your code and how it would help solve the question asked. You can update your answer by clicking on the *"[edit]"* link under the post. Thank you.